# Getting column name from result set using JavaScript in Snowflake?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, resultset

In Snowflake when we query using Javascript inside Stored procedure , we used to get [Result_set](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-resultset)  . How can we get Column name of the output result using Javascript API.???

Note: I am not asking about result column values which we can get using [.getColumnValue()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getColumnValue) or  [getColumnValueAsString](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getColumnValueAsString)  function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getColumnName`:

[Stored Procedure API - Object Statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-statement)

> A stored procedure Statement object provides the methods for executing a query statement and **accessing metadata** (such as column data types) about the statement.
>
> ---
>
> **getColumnName(colIdx)**
>
> This method returns the **name** of the specified column.
>
> Parameters
>
> The index number of the column (starting from 1, not 0).

For instance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var sql_command = "SELECT 10 as col";
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    return stmt.getColumnName(1);
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly . Do we really need to execute the prepared statement ? I think we can skip part .

Comment: @Paul According to doc: "Throws a JavaScript Error if:    The Statement has not yet been executed"